# In a Multi-Stage YAML Azure DevOps Pipeline, Does the Release Stage not have access to Source?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to limit the amount of work done by a multi-stage Azure DevOps pipeline by doing the configuration transforms in Python instead of doing them in MSBuild.  Ideally I would do these transforms in the Build stage. The problem I am running into is that the Build stage doesn't seem to have access to the Sources directory (ie $(Build.SourcesDirectory)).  Is there a way to grant the Release stage access to the Sources directory or is this enforced for deep-seated security reasons?

Answer (score 1):

`deployment` jobs automatically download artifacts, but don't checkout source.

Non-`deployment` jobs automatically checkout source, but don't download artifacts.

You can control this behavior by adding a `checkout` step or `download` step, as appropriate for the type of job and your requirements for that job.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops

> A deployment job doesn't automatically clone the source repo. You can checkout the source repo within your job with checkout: self. Deployment jobs only support one checkout step.